# How to detect what is dragged by mouse?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to acquire whatever I'm dragging with my mouse cursor over a `BorderPane` in JavaFX.

How does one go about reading what is being currently carried by the mouse cursor, specifically when the *On Drag Dropped* event is triggered?

There is a `getPickType` function in the `MouseEvent` class that's the argument of the callback function for the *On Drag Dropped* event, however no documentation is provided for it in the JavaFX library installation I have. I wanted to make sure I'm looking at the right thing here.

Comment: The [parameter type for `onDragDropped` is an `EventHandler<DragEvent>`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnDragDropped(javafx.event.EventHandler)), not an `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`, so the parameter passed to the `handle()` method is `DragEvent`. The [JavaDocs for `DragEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/DragEvent.html) show how to get the data being dragged from the `Dragboard`.

Comment: As an aside, this doesn't always work perfectly cleanly, especially if you are dragging and dropping data represented by user defined classes. I've often found the need to either put `String` data on the `Dragboard` from which I can reliably look up the data being dragged, or create some external mechanism to store the dragged data when the drag is initiated.

Comment: See the [Oracle drag and drop tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag-drop.htm) and [paper doll app](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/paper-doll.htm).